# How to use nested quotes when calling a powershell script in another powershell script file

Tags: json, powershell, serialization

I want to do the following call in a powershell script file:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://myservice.com `
  -ContentType application/json -Method POST `
  -Body '{"jsonproperty1": 200, "jsonproperty2": 1}'
```

This script works perfectly fine when executed in a powershell. However when I try to run it as:

```
powershell -C 'Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://myservice.com -ContentType application/json -Method POST -Body '{"jsonproperty1": 200, "jsonproperty2": 1}''
```

I can't seem to get it to work. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197381/how-can-i-use-nested-quotes-when-calling-a-powershell-script-within-a-batch-file) question, but the answer there doesnt work in my case.
I have tried all possible combinations of `'`, `"` and `` ` ``,using different escaping techniques, that I can think of. But I keep getting 400 Bad Request from my API, which I assume is because the jsonbody cant be serialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your `powershell -C` command line:

- **You're using *embedded* `'` chars. inside your overall `'...'` command string *without escaping them***; escape them as `''`.
- Sadly, **you *additionally* need to `\`-escape the embedded `"` chars., even though you shouldn't have to**; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375) explains why.

Therefore:

```
powershell -C 'Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://myservice.com -ContentType application/json -Method POST -Body ''{\"jsonproperty1\": 200, \"jsonproperty2\": 1}'''
```

---

However, you can **avoid these quoting headaches by passing a *script block* (`{ ... }`) to the PowerShell CLI**, but note that this **only works from *inside* PowerShell**):

```
# Use a script block, which requires no escaping.
powershell { 
  Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://myservice.com `
     -ContentType application/json -Method POST `
     -Body '{"jsonproperty1": 200, "jsonproperty2": 1}' 
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @FredrikEk.